# Source file documentation syntax

Tags: documentation, javadoc, documentation-generation

I'm looking for resources on various code/API documentation syntaxes, such as Javadocs. Are there any other widely used documentation syntaxes? I'm specifically looking for those used in association with C, C++/Objective C/Cocoa, Shell Scripts (if any) and Java, with PHP/Ruby/Python and the like being a second priority.

Thanks for any help.

P.S. - Do people use Javadoc syntax in C/C++/Objec-C projects, or not so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot people use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) which understands C++, C, Java, Objective-C, Python, Fortran, VHDL, PHP, C and more.

Doxygen has its own syntax but can also be used with JavaDoc, the MS-XML-Commenttags or the Markdown-Syntax. The OpenOffice uses f.ex. doxygen for it's API-documentation with the JavaDoc syntax, because it can be used for Java- and C-sources.